# Converting an equation into a way java script can interpret it

Tags: javascript, math, latitude-longitude, equation

So I have this code that is meant to do this equation:

```
(1 / 15) * arccos(-tan(L) * tan(23.44 * sin(360 * (D + 284) / 365)))
```

and for testing purposes alert it! But for some reason it returns "NaN". I've probably done something really stupid :P

```javascript
var now = new Date();
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - start;
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var d = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);


var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long = position.coords.longitude;
var tanlat = Math.atan(lat); 
var tantwentythree = Math.tan(23.44);
var dayplus = d + 284;
var sinday = Math.sin(360 * dayplus);
var arccos = Math.acos(tanlat);
var start = 1 / 15;
var equation = start * arccos * tantwentythree * sinday / 365;
alert(equation);


var result = rad2deg / 15 * Math.acos(-Math.tan(lat*deg2rad) * Math.tan(23.44*deg2rad * Math.sin(360*deg2rad * (day + 284) / 365)));
alert(result);
var resultstr = string(result);
document.getElementById('sunrise').innerHTML = resultstr;
```

I have a  with the id "sunrise", when the function is run, the var resultstr should be added to the  (i think?) But i doesn't!

Comment: `position.coords.latitude` is probably a string.

Comment: @SLaks, judging by http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html they are doubles

Comment: Add the following "alerts": `alert(start); alert(arccos); alert(tantwentythree); alert(sinday);` to spot the `NaN` factor

Comment: I get the NaN on arccos, so i guess that position.coords.latitude; is a string...

Comment: var latint= parseInt(lat);
would that do it?

Comment: you get the NaN on arccos because the argument is not in the [-1, 1] range. The latitude is probably a double (a number) already, the problems are elsewhere

Comment: @SLaks—not necessarily a problem, before processing the [Math functions](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2) call [*ToNumber*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) on the arguments.

Comment: @RobG: I can only repeat: according to http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#coordinates_interface the latitude is a double, i.e., a number

Comment: @WalterTross—yes, I was just pointing out that *even if* the values are strings, the Math functions will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you wanted

```
tanlat= Math.tan(lat)
```

not `Math.atan(lat)` which is the inverse...

But then you have another problem: all the arguments to the trigonometric functions should be radians, not degrees. You will have to multiply degrees by `Math.PI / 180`

But then you have even more problems. The `tan(23.44)` is not a quantity you need, you need the `tan` of a product, to start with.

What I would do is simply take your formula as it is, adding only the degrees to radians conversion:

```
var deg2rad = Math.PI / 180;
var rad2deg = 180 / Math.PI;
var result = rad2deg / 15 * Math.acos(-Math.tan(lat*deg2rad) *
             Math.tan(23.44*deg2rad * Math.sin(360*deg2rad * (d + 284) / 365)))
```

Comment: Oh, yeah -tan() isn't the same as inverse tan :/

Comment: Ok so for every single argument i'd do variable*Math.PI/180?

Comment: yes, if the argument is in degrees. @GeorgeTaylor, are you sure of your starting formula? If you are, then my solution should work (I have only renamed `equation` to `result`, since equation refers to both the left and the right side of an equality)

Comment: (1 / 15) * arccos(-tan(L) * tan(23.44 * sin(360 * (D + 284) / 365))):
Is definitely the starting formula! I will try your code :)

Comment: result = 0.11340350177467465
The equation in a calculator equal 4.94...
Whats going on?

Comment: lat=51.0890275

d=296

Comment: @GeorgeTaylor, I forgot that you were probably interested in the result in degrees. I fixed that

Comment: Thanks very much! Sorry for taking up your time:)

Comment: i've updated my question ^ Could you help me with another thing?

Comment: @GeorgeTaylor, you should not change your question! Anyway, I don't know of a string() function. I guess you meant `var resultstr = result.toString();`